# Responsive code ceases to work after manually toggling a DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, responsive-design

I have two divs. I want the left div to hide and show automatically according to the window size, i.e. I want it to be responsive.

On the other hand, I want to hide/show the left div manually if necessary. I added a black separator in the middle. When the separator is clicked the left div hides and the right div takes the whole width.

Until now, everything is ok.

BUT. When I hide/show the left div manually, it ceases to react to the responsive code.

Please check this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/joaorodr84/tmx3p6ts/14/) and lend me some help.

Thank you very much.

```
<html>

    <head>

        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <style>
            .div1 {
                background-color: #ffee99;
                width: 300px;
                height: 100%;
                position: absolute;
                top: 0px;
                left: 0px;
            }

            .separator {
                border-left: 3px solid #000000;
                border-right: 3px solid #000000;
                width: 0px;
                height: 100%;
                position: absolute;
                top: 0px;
                left: 300px;
                z-index: 100;
            }

            .div2 {
                background-color: #99eeff;
                width: calc(100% - 300px);
                height: 100%;
                position: absolute;
                top: 0px;
                left: 300px;
            }

            @media screen and (max-width: 500px) {

                .div {
                    display: none;
                }

                .separator {
                    left: 0px;
                }

                .div2 {
                    width: 100%;
                    left: 0;
                }

            }

        </style>

        <script>

            $(function() {

                function hideLeftDiv() {
                    $('.div1').hide();
                    $('.div2').css('width', '100%').css('left', 0);
                    $('.separator').css('left', '0px');
                }

                function showLeftDiv() {
                    $('.div1').show();
                    $('.div2').css('width', 'calc(100% - 300px)').css('left', '300px');
                    $('.separator').css('left', '300px');
                }

                $('.separator').click(function() {
                    $('.div1').is(":visible") ? hideLeftDiv() : showLeftDiv();
                });

            });

        </script>

    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="div1"></div>
        <div class="separator"></div>
        <div class="div2"></div>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Why don't you just use bootstrap?

Comment: Because I didn't know I could use bootstrap for this. Could you please show me how? Thanks a lot. :)

Answer (score 1):

Have a play with having two classes for identifying whether something is hidden or not i.e. desktop and mobile. You can then check whether its actually hidden with `is(':hidden')` and respond accordingly.

Check this fiddle for a quick demo http://fiddle.jshell.net/tmx3p6ts/31/

Comment: Thanks @andyw. You solution is pretty good, but it still has a bug. --- 1) Start with a small window. --- 2) Open and close the left div by clicking twice on the separator. --- 3) Stretch the window to PC width and notice that the left div does not open automatically as it should.

Answer (score 0):

Read this: [getbootstrap.com/css/#grid](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) You can use the grid system to make a page like you have, but when the screen is getting to small, you can [getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities) use this link to know when to hide things.

So to help you maybe a step in the right direction:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-sm-4 hidden-xs">
        This is the left div.
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-12">
        This is the left div.
    </div>
</div>
```

Something like this should work. Check out this fiddle: [Fiddle with bootstrap](http://jsfiddle.net/m37evm45/1/)

You can adjust the classes to any style you want.